# Do lite version and full version need to have same provision/bundle identifier or not?

Tags: iphone

Do the lite version and the full version of an app need to have same provision/bundle identifier or not?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *must not* have the same bundle identifier. The bundle ID is used by Apple to distinguish one app from another in iTunes Connect, in the App Store, and on a user's device.

Comment: Thanks. But if the lite version has created some files, how can the users just upgrade from lite version to full version to reuse the created files by the lite version?

Comment: Do I need to construct the file transfer function bewteen the lite version and the full version?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem you need to solve. Here's a good article by Stephen Lombardo with a solution: http://mobileorchard.com/lite-to-paid-iphone-application-data-migrations-with-custom-url-handlers/

Comment: I misunderstand your answer. Do you mean both cases : same bundle identifiers and different identifiers are allowed?